# Avoiding certain strings from a table dynamically

Tags: postgresql

I have a table contains customer details and i need to exclude certain emails from specific domains(identified from email string) from my table.
How can i do that?

Tried with below but is not working any idea or suggestions ?

PostgreSQL Version 11

```
WITH CTE AS
(
select 'gmail.com' as name
union
select 'yahoo.com'
) 
,base as
(
    SELECT 'email ILIKE ''%'||name||'%''OR' as emails FROM CTE
)
,finals as
(
    SELECT string_agg(emails, '  ') as con FROM base
)
SELECT * FROm customers
WHERE  (SELECT con FROM finals )
```

Error i'm getting,

```
ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type text
LINE 16: WHERE  (SELECT con FROM finals )
                ^
SQL state: 42804
Character: 242
```

Comment: Please provide input sample data and expected output. What exactly is not working?

Comment: @S-ManI have updated my question and included the error message,Any suggestions here please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot construct an SQL string and run it in a single SQL statement.

But I think this could be done much simpler:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT 'gmail.com' AS name
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'yahoo.com'
) 
SELECT * FROM customers
WHERE email ILIKE ANY (SELECT '%' || name || '%' FROM cte);
```